# How to do padding for a matrix

Tags: c, matrix, padding

I am trying to do the padding for a basic matrix.

For example, I have a `3 * 3` matrix and I want to pad it to `7 * 7` matrix:

**3x3 Matrix**

> 1 2 3
>
> 4 5 6
>
> 7 8 9

Is there any efficient way to add 2 padding to on the matrix?

**7x7 Matrix After Padding**

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>
> 0 0 1 2 3 0 0
>
> 0 0 4 5 6 0 0
>
> 0 0 7 8 9 0 0
>
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your attempt.

Comment: C does not have any automatic facility for this. You will have to create a new matrix, copy the old data, and write zeros. Some C implementations may have features for this, such as vectorization, and some library, including libraries from system vendors and third parties, may have features for matrix operations like this.